# Non-equivalence of might and may

Tags: modal-verbs

> Although **might** may have become the main exponent of epistemic
> possibility in every day spoken English, it is generally not
> synonymous with **may**, as the following example, borrowed from Charreyre
> (1984: 55-56) illustrates:
>
> in **Just look at the sky! There might be a storm soon**, uttered in front
> of a threatening sky, it would be contextually less appropriate,
> Charreyre suggests, to use **may** instead of **might**, while **will** would be
> perfectly acceptable. **May** would convey very little information and
> simply express the logical, theoretical and objective possibility that
> such a sky is likely to bring about a storm, which is obvious. **Might**,
> on the other hand, carries some appreciation on the part of the
> speaker that, although a storm may not be wished for, yet it must not
> be ruled out.
>
> -- *[Towards a contextual micro-analysis of the non-equivalence of might and could](https://books.google.com/books?id=163_PDnaeZsC&pg=PA96)* by Stephane Gresset

Claude Charreyre is a French linguist, but I'm not sure his assessment on might vs. may can represent how a native speaker of English would think about it.

Do you think his conclusion was stretching it? Why?

Comment: This is pretty deep stuff. Is it from the forbidden section? / While I'd agree that 'may' and 'might' here are not exact synonyms, I'd say that most Anglophones would treat them as such except for register / idiomaticity. In fact, most Brits would use 'could' or 'There's going to be'.

Comment: Forbidden section? No, it was quoted in Gresset's paper.

Comment: Where was Gresset's paper published? Citation is important.

Comment: As a Brit, "It may rain later" and "It might rain later" express exactly the same sentiment. However "You might kill me" and "You may kill me" are very different!  "May " is generally only used where the meaning is unambiguous.

Comment: @JohnLawler Source added

Comment: As an American; 'may' is;  iffy - unsure - a possibility - with little to go on. 'Might' is similar, but, not the same; a possibility - not positive - could - a reasonable conclusion. "It may be a cold June this year." vs. "I might have a dessert after dinner tonight."

Comment: There is certainly a spectrum of certainty using 'could, may, might, should and will' in the sentence : 'There xxxxx be a storm soon'. My own impression is, as listed, that 'may' and 'might' are close but my own usage puts 'might' as slightly stronger than 'may'.

Comment: @KinzleB: Thank you very much; that's an excellent source, though many of the theories are a bit overelaborated. Still, that's the norm in the field. The fact -- which a perusal of the contents will show -- is that every facile English speaker has their own arrangement of modal auxiliaries and verbal constructions with modal senses (if not modal verbs per se, like _be going to_ and _have to_), and if they're at all good at using them, they already have their own way of arranging them into idioms. Which vary from person to person and group to group, as idioms do. No basic rules yet.

Comment: More [details on modal variation here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf).

Comment: You haven't given any dictionary definitions in your question that  would serve to contrast any different meanings of the two words. I've always used **may** in the sense of asking or wondering if I'm allowed to do—or capable of doing—something. (E.g., *May I have some more?* Will you allow me to have some more?) On the other hand, I've used **might** in the sense that there's a possibility of something happening. (E.g., *I'm tired and I might just stay in tonight.* We'll have to see what happens.)